# LINQ query on birth date to get age

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm runing a query (in northwind db) on the employees birth date and I want to get their age. How do i do that?

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (NorthWindDataContext dataContext = new NorthWindDataContext())
        {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

            var q1 = from z in dataContext.Employees
                     select new
                     {
                         z.FirstName,
                       today-z.BirthDate <---- problem  here
                     };

            dataGridView1.DataSource = q1;

        }
    }
```

in my final grid i want column of age.

birthdate = 29/05/1969 (example)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This can be tricky because you need to make sure the birthday has passed this year, otherwise your age will be out by one.

```
var query = from e in dataContext.Employees
            //get the difference in years since the birthdate
            let years = DateTime.Now.Year - e.BirthDate.Year
            //get the date of the birthday this year
            let birthdayThisYear = e.BirthDate.AddYears(years)
            select new
            {
                //if the birthday hasn't passed yet this year we need years - 1
                Age = birthdayThisYear > DateTime.Now ? years - 1 : years
            };
```

Doing it this way has the advantage of calculating the age in the generated SQL query.  This means you don't need to iterate through the result set on the client side to calculate the age.

In case you're interested, it will produce the following SQL:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 2013
DECLARE @p1 DateTime = '2013-02-14 09:08:46.413'
DECLARE @p2 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t2].[value] AS [years], [t2].[value2] AS [birthdayThisYear], 
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t2].[value2] > @p1 THEN [t2].[value] - @p2
        ELSE [t2].[value]
     END) AS [Age]
FROM (
    SELECT [t1].[value], DATEADD(YEAR, [t1].[value], [t1].[BirthDate]) AS [value2]
    FROM (
        SELECT [t0].[BirthDate], @p0 - DATEPART(Year, [t0].[BirthDate]) AS [value]
        FROM [Employees] AS [t0]
        ) AS [t1]
    ) AS [t2]
```

Comment: Great answer. Just adding in my code, to this work, I replaced the line "e.BirthDate.AddYears(years)" with DbFunctions.AddYears(e.BirthDate, years) and everything goes fine

Answer (score 6):

Create anonymous object that has 3 properties: `FirstName`, `Age` and `BirthDate` (this is needed for check if employee birthday has passed this year or not).

```
var q1 = (from z in dataContext.Employees
    select new
    {
         FirstName = z.FirstName,
         Age = today.Year - z.BirthDate.Year,
         BirthDate = z.BirthDate
    }).ToList();

q1.ForEach(x => if (x.BirthDate > today.AddYears(-x.Age)) { x.Age--; });
```

According to comments (that are right) you should also check if `BirthDate` has passed or not, so after selecting data you have to run check for that.

Comment: How will this change before and after a persons birthday passes?

Comment: This won't work if the birth day hasn't passed yet this year.  It will report an age that is one year too high in that situation.

Comment: This has got the drawback of needing to caluculate the age on the client side because of the foreach.  Check out my answer for a solution that calculates the age in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You need a named property, something like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (NorthWindDataContext dataContext = new NorthWindDataContext())
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

        var q1 = from z in dataContext.Employees
                 select new
                 {
                     Name = z.FirstName,
                     Age = today - z.BirthDate
                 };

        dataGridView1.DataSource = q1;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = from o in dataContext.Employees
    select new
    {
         FirstName = o.FirstName,
         Age = DateTime.Now.Year - z.BirthDate.Year -1
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var q1 = from z in dataContext.Employees
          select new
         {
            z.FirstName,
            z.BirthDate,
            Age = DateTime.Now.Year - z.BirthDate.Year
         };
```

Comment: It wasn't me, but I'm guessing that the downvote is because it's a minus, not a hyphen

Comment: @DoctorJones yes - upon further inspection I realised he declared the variable today.  Bit too early :-)