# Calculate age from dateofbirth column in the datatable using LINQ query?

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0

I have a datatable with Name and DateOfBirth column, i want to query the datatable to calculate Age using LINQ query.

Comment: Why not just bring back the date-of-birth as a regular column / cell, and perform the age calculation in the .net code (perhaps when rendering it); then it will be trivial. To do it in LINQ requires knowledge of which ORM you are using, as there are different ways to access inbuilt functions like `datediff` in each one

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14871056/linq-query-on-birth-date-to-get-age or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age

Comment: i used c sharp code calculation and found it too simple. thanks marc,kosta,anaximander ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int Age = DateTime.Now.Year - BirthDate.Year
```